# Excel List Auto Transfer

Tags: excel

I have a list of names on say Sheet1 i.e.:

Bob
Joe
Smith

and I need the list to be exactly the same on Sheet2, which I used =Sheet1!A1 or close to it, my question is I need to be able to insert a line on Sheet1, with say a new employee getting hired, and the lines be auto inserted into the other sheets, I have a lot of sheets that need to use the list on Sheet1 and the formulas that line up in each column, so when I insert a line on sheet one it inserts a line on the other sheets, and moves the formulas down and corrects their Ranges, say I insert a line at column 6 with a formula (A6:D6), then column 6 (now 7) should have a range of (A7:D7)

Comment: Q is a bit unclear, so not sure if this is wahat you need. In sheet 2 you can use the formula `=INDIRECT("Sheet1!RC1",FALSE)` This will always return from `Sheet1` Column `A` from the same row the formula is in, regardless of what you do to Sheet1

Answer (score 0):

You could get around this by using INDIRECT:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!R"&ROW()&"C"&COLUMN(),FALSE)
```

FALSE allows a R1C1 style reference (Row 1 Column 1).  This would automatically stay attached to the proper row without getting updated.

Comment: So if I add a column to sheet1 and put a name in there, because our list is alphabetical, then it will update the rest of the lists with the names without me having to go individually and putting that person in.

Comment: Yes (although you need to make sure your formula extends beyond the end of your data in order to accommodate for future row/columns)

Comment: This formula isn't working for me, in my Excel Workbook I have a sheet where the List of names starts at A2 and I need the formula to start at B3 in all my other sheets, I get a Reference error in your formula even when I change the Sheet1 to the correct name.